# How to add CHECK constraints using multiple columns in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, syntax-error

I'm having trouble modelling this disjoint in Postgresql. Error message shows:

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "or"
LINE 2:  add constraint group_collection or user_collection Check (g...
^
What could I do to fix this issue?

```
create table collections(
collectionId    serial,
title           TitleValue,
description     text,
key             integer not null,
group_coll_id   integer,
user_coll_id    integer,
primary key (collectionId),
foreign key (key) references photos(photoid)
```

----photos is from a previous table---
);

```
create table group_collection(
group_coll_id   integer,
owns            integer not null,
primary key (group_coll_id),
foreign key (group_coll_id) references collections(collectionId),
foreign key (owns) references groups(groupid)
```

);

```
create table user_collection(
user_coll_id    integer,
owns            integer not null,
primary key (user_coll_id),
foreign key (user_coll_id) references collections(collectionId),
foreign key (owns) references users(userid)
```

);

```
alter table collections add constraint  fk_collections_group foreign key (group_coll_id) references group_collection(group_coll_id);
alter table collections add constraint  fk_collections_user foreign key (user_coll_id) references user_collection(user_coll_id);
alter table only collections
add constraint group_collection or user_collection Check (group_coll_id is null or user_coll_id is null)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SO. You're naming your constraint `group_collection or user_collection`, which isn't a valid label :)

The `ADD CONSTRAINT` syntax for a table `CREATE TABLE t (x INT, y INT);` should be

```
    ALTER TABLE t ADD CONSTRAINT any_label CHECK (x IS NULL OR y IS NULL)
```

This should work in your case:

```
alter table collections
add constraint mycheck check (group_coll_id is null or user_coll_id is null)
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=293c8d1c5faa9ddba635dfdaf2a29b8e)